# How to tell if ASP.NET impersonation is working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, impersonation

With ASP.NET impersonation, can one use `Environment.UserName` to determine if impersonation is working?  That is if the site is impersonating properly, should `Environment.UserName` return my username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `User.Identity.Name`:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // If we got so far it means that the user is authorized to 
    // execute this action according to our configuration => 
    // we can work with his username
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wait, i'm pretty sure Identity.Name has the name of user regardless of whether impersonation is enabled or not.